# Можно ли установить NFC на телефон?

Tags: nfc

Хочу заняться разработкой приложений с использованием NFC.

NFC в телефоне нет.

Почитал в интернете и вроде его можно установить как модуль с помощью **NFC антенны** или **NFC симки**. Но будет ли видеть телефон этот NFC? Вроде требуется ещё прошивка. В сведениях об аппаратном обеспечении о NFC ни слова

Модель телефона: ASUS Z00ED

[image: Сведения о телефоне]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя есть *инженер* или ты знаешь как установить антену правильно, а затем написать *низкоуровневый софт*, затем *внедрить его в образ прошивки* телефона, затем прошить телефон.

**Легче купить телефон дороже**

Comment: А поповоду симок - это просто как карта банка с NFC. Телефону никакого порта NFC не несет. Ну и достать ее тяжело